# Z-indexing issue with fixed background on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my first project ever and I'm running into a weird issue with z-indexing on mobile devices. If you visit https://kylemneal.github.io/mfa-repo/index.html about 3/4 of the way down there's a fixed background that is z-indexed to the back. This shows up great on all desktop browsers that I have tested (chrome, firefox, safari) but on mobile devices the fixed background z-indexes to the front and is laid over the whole page.

Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/74urqj3mok9d38d/IMG_2621.PNG?dl=0

When using device view on all three browsers I do not see this issue. I only see this when I'm using a mobile device. Has anyone seen this type of thing before?

https://github.com/kylemneal/mfa-repo

Comment: i'm confused-- you say it's z-indexed "to the back" but it appears to have a super high z-index of 1000?

Comment: I tested your work in my phone, it is working fine.

Comment: Holy shit, thank you for catching that. That was supposed to be -1000. 

I changed that value and now the fixed background falls behind images, but still doesn't fall behind the white background. Gonna see if I can tweak that. 

Still super weird that this only is a problem on mobile devices. I don't understand why this wouldn't happen on desktop too.

Comment: @carljohnson may I ask what phone you are using? I'm trying to figure out if this is just iOS or if this is just some seemingly random devices that have this issue.

Comment: @kneal I am using android with chrome browser (my [phone](https://www.mi.com/in/redmi-note-6-pro/)). If you're using IOS then try to run your file also in chrome not just safari.

Comment: It works on my phone as well (iOS 13.x)

Comment: @carljohnson thanks so much. Seems to be an intermittent issue that is only effecting some iOS devices. I checked in safari, chrome and firefox on my iphone and I get the same thing. Super weird. Thanks for the info!